# Share SVG xml in the facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is possible share `svg` in the `facebook`?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

Of course, the file may have more detailed images.

I´m using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)

Comment: This is not possible AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what do you mean, but if you mean to share a svg image somewhere, you can try the image tag:

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;...svgdata....' />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have now realized that facebook does not accept image in SVG format, but really need to understand the best way to have a share button image created on canvas on facebook. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: use the canvas.toDataUrl() function to get a png or a jpg and then share it. For particular share a jpg on facebook i cannot help.